# How to track an inactive mouse once a page loads?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener, mousemove, debouncing

Right now, I have a function set up to do something if a mouse is inactive for 10 seconds **for mobile only**. However my console.log doesn't appear unless there is some activity **before** it is triggered by the inactivity. here is my code:

```
    if (width <= 480) {
       const inactiveUserMessage = () => {
             console.log("mouse has been inactive for 10 seconds");
       };
       document.addEventListener("mousemove", debounce(inactiveUserMessage, 10000));
    }
```

***In another file, lives the debounce function:

```
export function debounce(func, timeout) {
    let timer;
    return (...args) => {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            func.apply(this, args);
        }, timeout);
    };
}
```

There needs to be some kind of activity before the inactiveUserMessage triggers. However how do i do it where the debounce function runs right away without needing some kind of movement before?? Please help!!!

Please let me know if this makes sense or if you need some more information.

I tried to create a mousemove event listener with a debounce function but it doesn't work unless there is some kind of movement on the page before hand.

I tried to create a mousemove event listener with a debounce function but it doesn't work unless there is some kind of movement on the page before hand.

Comment: @BernardBorg that doesn't really answer my question, it looks like her mousemove event wasn't firing on the page at all. My event fires only when there's mouse activity FIRST, then it fires. I want it to fire once the page loads without needing mouse activity beforehand.

Comment: Oh, I  get your question now

Comment: I'm not certain if your case falls into this, but this may be intentional browser policy; some browsers limit what pages can do until after there has been some real user interaction (to prevent e.g. notifications or videos autoplaying in a hidden window, etc).

Comment: @BernardBorg Your solution worked!!! Thank you so much!! I like the way you rearranged so the inactiveUserMessage is outside the eventListener. The only thing is the popup shows up every 10 seconds even if I clicked out of it the first time. How do I get it to appear just once and not show up again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the window's "load" event to start the timer and pass the timer to the debounce function. Something like this;

```js
let timer;
const inactiveUserMessage = () => {
     console.log("mouse has been inactive for 10 seconds");
};

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
     timer = setTimeout(inactiveUserMessage, 10000);
});

...

if (width <= 480) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", debounce(inactiveUserMessage, 10000), timer);
}
...
```

```js
export function debounce(func, timeout, timer) {
    return (...args) => {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            func.apply(this, args);
        }, timeout);
    };
}
```

Comment: @SchneiderG Please mark the answer as approved so that people can be confident that the answer works in the future